# Can't use func on for loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve Euler's Problem 22. I made almost every thing but ı couln't get the answer.

1. I made a name dict with keys are names and values are the order of them.
2. I create a alphabetical dict witch every letter has point on the order

   {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, .... 'Y': 25, 'Z': 26}
3. Defined a function witch makes every name in for loop and gives every letter a point and sum them ups

   (for 'COLIN'  c:3, o:15,...)

```
 name_point = 0
 for letter in name:
     name_point += (alphabet.get(letter))
 return name_point`enter code here
```

4. And when ı try to do

```
    for name in name_dict.keys():
    x =name_pointer(name)
```

this error belows

```
name_point += (alphabet.get(letter))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

5. But when ı dont use for loop

```
    x = name_dict.get('COLIN')
    print(name_pointer('COLIN')*x)
```

> it gives me what ı want, but just for one name

```
49714
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_points(letter):
    return ord(letter.lower()) - ord('a') + 1

def score_name(name):
    return sum(get_points(l) for l in name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the call to `alphabet.get`. `alphabet` is a `dict`, and the `get` method is used to get the value of a certain key. If the key is not found, `None` will be returned by default (see the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)).

You can set the `default` argument to `0`, so keys that are not found do not add to your sum.

```
alphabet.get(letter, 0)
```